# Mockserver in dev profile spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, mockserver

Can I uses mockserver in spring boot to mock a server (mock al request to ...), but not in a integration test?

I mean... Running in a dev or local profile to uses jmeter and take measurements to detect memory leaks etc.

Did you something similar can you give me an example or an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, your question is too peripheral and is not specific enough to get meaningful  answers here. Could you please add more details on what you have already tried and where you are stuck at? It would be great if you could rephrase it after you see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are asking two questions in one. a: Can you use a mock server at all? b: How can I configure my environment to prevent a mock server from being used once I've configured if I'm running integration testing? I would suggest get assume one and ask the other. If you can TRY to run the mock server and show the results here that would be better. Questions of yes or no followed by requesting an example without giving any information as to what needs troubleshooting do not get traction.